# CodePen CSS not displaying properly

Tags: css, codepen

https://codepen.io/jamesbcn/pen/weYdPw

I'm attempting to copy and paste a navigation bar, that I'm working on into CodePen but the CSS is not being displayed properly.

```
.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0px;
  height: 90px;
}
.navbar-brand>img {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 5px;
  width: auto;
  margin: center;
}
.nav >li >a {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.nav ul{
    display: flex;
    background-color: #C2A76F;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav ul a{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid white;
}

.nav ul a:hover{
    background-color: #816F4A;
}

.nav li{
    flex: 1 1 0;
}

p{
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Not displaying properly how? What do you expect to see?

Comment: Please provide a better descriptive question, of what issue you are facing, what you want to achieve, etc. Thanks

Comment: Apologies. I think you looked at the code when I removed the css. Please click once more and you will see that the css is not displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems there, one being the structure in your HTML doesnt look like it matches what you're expecting in your CSS, and the other being that you're treating `nav` as a css class, rather than an element (Prefixing a css term with a period means the browser is trying to match an element with a css class like `<div class='nav'></div>`, rather than the HTML element `<nav>`).

E.g.

```
.nav >li >a {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

should be

```
nav >li >a {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I accidentally removed the "nav" class tag when removing Angular-related code from the same div. Thank you for spotting that.